# Can google cloud storage run a check over a backed up folder on my hd and update only files that've changed?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Using google cloud storage to back up files on my hard drive...

I don't need to back everything up -- just selected folders, and files within those folders.

After I've made changes to some files in a backed up folder, can I get google cloud storage to run a check over a backed-up folder, and update only those files that I've updated? Without re-copying all files in the folder?

I'm not a coder -- so if there's a simple-to-a-non-coder way to do this, that'd be best.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not a coder, the product you're looking for (from Google) is Google Drive. Google Cloud Storage is an enterprise solution that's primarily built around a developer API to meet the needs of businesses (and developers).

Google Drive would (probably) work well for your use case. When the Google Drive client is open, changed files (only) will be backed up immediately. Unmodified files will not be uploaded. You can schedule the sync by opening and closing the Google Drive client. Finally, using Google Drive, you can selectively sync specific folders, which meets your use case.

Get the Google Drive client by going to https://drive.google.com/ and pressing the "Connect Drive to your desktop" link at the left.